# beautiful soup and requests not pulling text from webpage - Python3

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the current currency exchange rates. This is my script so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Collect and parse first page
page = requests.get('https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/? 
Amount=1&From=GBP&To=USD')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')

c_rate=soup.find(class_='converterresult-conversionTo')
```

however when i `print(soup)` it pulls meta content and link href, I've played around with the parsers and the same problem happens with 'html.parser' aswell

Any ideas?, if you go on the page im trying to pull the 1.30451 figure out.

Thanks,

Comment: Did you actually look at the page your requesting and seeing what response your getting back? Is it the HTML your accepting? I would also look at all requests that happen when you load that link.

Comment: @antfuentes87 yeah the it says response[200] and the link is the webpage i want to scrape from, but i cant get the tags and anchors, it just pulls out metadata

Comment: That is my point... look at that response. They are using reactjs so that data your looking for is not in the page you are requesting (it is loaded from other requests). Load the page with chrome dev tools open (network tab) and look at all the request. Look at the ones that are `xhr` or `fetch` (I think saw like 5 or 6 requests that are requesting .php files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium can help you do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?%20Amount=1&From=GBP&To=USD'
browser=webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)

soup=BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source)

rate = soup.select("a[href*=https://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=GBP&to=]")[1]
print(rate.text)
```

Output:

```
1.30449
```

If you change `[1]`, in the `rate` variable to `[2]`, `[3]` or `[4]`, you should the GPB exchange rates for EUR, INR and AUD, respectively.